# Printers. How many lines of text can fit into one page?

Tags: printing

First, I'd like to apologize in advance if I have posted this on the wrong website in the stack-xyz network.

My question is simple.

Does anyone know of a printer that can print the most amount of lines in a single page? What I mean is, is there a printer that can print so small but still legible characters achieving the most amount of lines per page?

Please don't be mad and vote me down to oblivion. If I was wrong to create this post I'll kindly remove it. I just want to know.